# Difference between a function and a mathematical expression

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, logic

This question may not make much sense but I would appreciate it if someone could give me a hint.

Take limits of functions for example. Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $x_0$ be a limit point of $X$, $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function, and $L\in\mathbb{R}$. If the $\varepsilon -\delta$ criterion is satisfied, then we write $lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=L$. The definition seems to suggest that we should write **"function signs"** (e.g.,$f(x)$) after the symbol "$lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}$". (It seems to me that function signs are a special kind of mathematical expressions of the form $\Theta(x)$, where $\Theta$ is a function.)

Now suppose that $g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is also a function. Then we have their sum $f+g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. If $lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=L$ and $lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}g(x)=M$, then we can prove the fact that $f+g$ converges to $L+M$ at $x_0$, for which we write $lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}(f+g)(x)=L+M$. I'm totally fine with this.

**Now I'm going to explain what confuses me. People usually don't write $lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}(f+g)(x)=L+M$, but write $lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}( f(x)+g(x))=L+M$ instead.**

But we should write function signs rather than expressions (that are not function signs) after "$lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}$". $f(x), g(x)$ and $(f+g)(x)$ are all function signs because $f,g$ and $f+g$ are functions. $f(x)+g(x)$ is indeed a **mathematical expression** (of the elements of $X$), but **not a function sign**. Is it legitimate to write $lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}( f(x)+g(x))=L+M$ ?

Similarly, I'm confused about the question of whether it is legitimate to write symbols such as $lim_{x\rightarrow1}x^2 =1$ (since $x^2$ is an expression rather than a function sign),$\int cf(x) dx$ ( $(cf)(x)$ is a function sign but $cf(x)$ is not),
and $\sum_{x\in X}|f(x)|$ (the absolute value $|f(x)|$ is an expression rather than a function sign), etc?

Comment: well, it seems that the expression following $\lim_{x \to x_0}$ should be a function. Indeed, $f(x) + g(x)$ is a function, for it is a composition of functions. Furthermore, by definition, $(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$. So I think both expressions are alright, and should mean the same thing.

Comment: when we have $\lim_{x \to 1} = x+2 = 3$, we don't have an expression that you would call a "function sign" after $\lim_{x\to 1}$, yet this is standard and non-ambiguous notation

Comment: A mathematical expression describes a mathematical object: number, function,...